# tex4ebook or tex4ht: confliction of amsart, hyperref and `\part`?

Tags: hyperref, tex4ht, amsart, tex4ebook

The test code:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\part{Part1}

\section{Sec1}

\section{Sec2}

\part{Part2}

\end{document}
```

Compiled with tex4ebook, it returns with `! Use of \n:no@part: doesn't match its definition.`

I wonder a workaround for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be clash between `amsart.4ht` and `nameref.4ht`. Try the updated `nameref.4ht`:

```
% nameref.4ht (2019-04-12-10:50), generated from tex4ht-4ht.tex
% Copyright 2005-2009 Eitan M. Gurari
% Copyright 2009-2019 TeX Users Group
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License, either
% version 1.3c of this license or (at your option) any
% later version. The latest version of this license is in
%   http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
% and version 1.3c or later is part of all distributions
% of LaTeX version 2005/12/01 or later.
%
% This work has the LPPL maintenance status "maintained".
%
% The Current Maintainer of this work
% is the TeX4ht Project <http://tug.org/tex4ht>.
%
% If you modify this program, changing the
% version identification would be appreciated.
\immediate\write-1{version 2019-04-12-10:50}

   \let\NR:Type\relax
\let\ltx@label\label
\def\prf:label{{\ifx \NR:Title\:UnDef \else \NR:Title\fi}%
               {\ifx \NR:Type\relax \else \NR:Type .1\fi}{}}%
\let\NR:StartSec\:StartSec
\let\NR:no@sect\no@sect
\def\no@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{\gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
    \NR:no@sect{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\def\:StartSec#1#2#3{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \NR:StartSec{#1}{#2}{#3}%
}

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#7}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@sect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}[{#7}]{#8}}
\HLet\NR@sect\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1#2#3#4#5{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\ssect:ttl}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{#1}%
   \o:NR@ssect:{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
}
\HLet\NR@ssect\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@part:[{#1}]{#2}}

% this definition clashes with asmart and amsproc classes, so we
% need to skip if these are active
\@ifundefined{opt@amsart.cls}{%
\@ifundefined{opt@amsproc.cls}{%
\HLet\no@part\:tempc
}{}}{}


\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{part}%
   \o:no@spart:{#1}}
\HLet\no@spart\:tempc

\def\:tempc[#1]#2{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1}}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
   \o:NR@chapter:[{#1}]{#2}}
\HLet\NR@chapter\:tempc

\def\:tempc#1{%
   \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel\sch:ttl}%
   \o:NR@schapter:{#1}%
   \gdef\NR:Type{chapter}%
}
\HLet\NR@schapter\:tempc

\let\o:NR@@caption\@caption
%
%
% Keith Andrews <kandrews@iicm.edu> reported that \@captype as
% \NR:Type threw an undefined control sequence error. I think
% \@currenvir is safe, there is nothing special about \@captype.
%
\long\def\@caption#1[#2]{%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#2}}%
   \o:NR@@caption{#1}[{#2}]%
}

\let\o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem\@opargbegintheorem
  \def\@opargbegintheorem#1#2#3{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#3}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \NR@gettitle{#3}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \o:NRorg@opargbegintheorem{#1}{#2}{#3}%
  }%

\let\o:NRorg@begintheorem\@begintheorem
  \def\@begintheorem#1#2{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{#1 #2}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{\@currenvir}%
    \defineautorefname{\@currenvir}{#1}%
    \NR@gettitle{}%
    \o:NRorg@begintheorem{#1}{#2}%
  }%

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \@ifpackageloaded{listings}{%
      \def\:tempc#1{%
         \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{listing}}%
         \gdef\NR:Type{lstlisting}%
         \o:NROrg@lst@MakeCaption:{#1}%
         \gdef\@currentlabelname{listing}}
      \HLet\NROrg@lst@MakeCaption\:tempc
  }{}%
  % bug [348]
  \def\:tempams{%
    \gdef\NR:Title{\a:newlabel{equation}}%
    \gdef\NR:Type{equation}%
    \gdef\@currentlabelname{equation}%
  }
  \@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
     \Configure{@begin}{align}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{boxed}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equations}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{gather}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{genfrac}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{measure@}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline*}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{multline}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{overset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{smallmatrix}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{split}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{subarray}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{substack}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{underset}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xleftarrow}{\:tempams}
     \Configure{@begin}{xrightarrow}{\:tempams}
  }{
     \Configure{@begin}{equation}{\:tempams}
}

}
\let\T:ref=\::ref
\def\::ref{\protect\T@ref}
\def\T@ref#1{%
  \@safe@activestrue
  \let\::ref \T:ref
  \expandafter\@setref\csname r@#1\endcsname\@firstoffive{#1}%
  \def\::ref{\protect\T@ref}%
  \@safe@activesfalse
}

\gdef\defineautorefname#1#2{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname #1autorefname\endcsname{#2}}
\defineautorefname{theorem}{Theorem}

\Configure{newlabel}
   {\csname cur:th\endcsname \csname :currentlabel\endcsname}
   {\string\csname\space :autoref\string\endcsname
     {\NR:Type}#1}

\ifx \@currentlabelname\:UnDef
   \let\@currentlabelname\empty
\fi

\pend:defIII\@setref{\edef\RefArg{##3}}
\append:defIII\@setref{\let\:autoref\:gobble}
\let\:autoref\:gobble


\Hinput{nameref}
\endinput
```

The important part is:

```
\@ifundefined{opt@amsart.cls}{% 
\@ifundefined{opt@amsproc.cls}{%
\HLet\no@part\:tempc
}{}}{}
```

It disables patches for the `\part` from `nameref.4ht` for `amsart` and `amsproc` classes.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand why there is no clash between (original) nameref.4ht and amsbook.4ht? In amsbook.4ht, there is also a re-definition of `\part`.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I don't understand it as well. when I copied the code from `amsbook.4ht` to `amsart.4ht`, it didn't work at all, so I came with this work around

Comment: I inserted `\tracingall` and try to read the `.log` file. The context of the error: `\n:no@part: [#1]#2->\gdef \NR:Title {\a:newlabel {#1}}\gdef \NR:Type {part}\o:no@part: [{#1}]{#2} ! Use of \n:no@part: doesn't match its definition.` Seemingly it is related to an optional argument. I tried to feed `\part` with an optional argument `\part[test]{Part1}`, along with `amsart` and `hyperref`, there is no clash.

Comment: I read the `amsart.cls` and `amsbook.cls`. I found that in both `amsart.cls` and `amsbook.cls`, `\part` accepts no optional argument, while in `amsbook.cls`, there is an addition optional argument version `\@part[#1]{#2}`. I see that in `amsbook.4ht`, `\no@part` is redirected by `\let\no@part\@part`, while in `amsart.4ht`, by `\let\no@part\part`, and `\no@part` forces an optional argument in `nameref.4ht`.

Comment: I don't know what a correct code should be, but it seems to me that there should be no definition of `\no@part` in `amsart.4ht`, according to the non-existence of `\@part` in `amsart.cls`, and accordingly in `nameref.4ht`, `\no@part` should be treated only if it is defined.

Comment: @Yai0Phah I've tried lot of solutions, but lot of them resulted in not printing the part, or printing without any html markup. The current solution seems hacky, which I don't like, but it is the only one I found that produces satisfactory result :(

Comment: I guess that the hyperlink references won't work for `\part` in your solution, but I didn't check it. It seems to me that in `amsart.4ht`, `\def\part{\rdef:sec{part}}` should be modified into some proper codes - I checked `article.4ht`, the `\part` is treated differently (without invoking `\rdef:sec`, while it's invoked in anything else like `\section`, etc).

Comment: @Yai0Phah I've tried to use the code from `article.4ht`, but it doesn't print the part at all :( but my solution seems to work with hyper references

Comment: Are there any upstream co-maintainer? It seems better to record this to the issue tracker and label this as a temporary workaround.

Comment: @Yai0Phah there are few more contributors, so you definitely should record it on the issue tracker